# Proof that if $A\subset B$ then $A^\circ \subset B^\circ$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Please let me know if you find my proof satisfactory. I'm somewhat concerned about the last paragraph of the proof below. This is "too evident to prove", thus the proof doesn't seem too easy, but I think it should look fine.

Let $A\subset B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $A^\circ$ is the interior of $A$.

If $\vec{x}\in A^\circ$ then $\exists \varepsilon >0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\subset A^\circ\subset A. \implies B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\subset B$.

Now suppose that $B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\cap ∂B\ne \emptyset$ ($∂B$ is the boundary of $B$). Then $B_\varepsilon\vec(x)\not\subset B$ and $A\not\subset B$, which is a contradiction. Thus $B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\subset B^\circ. \implies A^\circ \subset B^\circ$.

Comment: After your first two sentences, it is all over, you have proved that $x$ is in the interior of $B$.

Comment: Just want to make sure the proof is as rigorous as I can make it such.

Comment: There is a logic/notation glitch in your second sentence. You should not have $\implies$. Just before the $\implies$ you should have a period. Then you can say "This implies that $\dots$."  Or "It follows that $\dots$, and therefore $x$ is in $B^{\circ}$.

Comment: You might use that the interior of $A$ is the largest open set that is contained in $A$.